# Spring rest template with aws x-ray

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-xray

I would like to trace calls between spring micro services deployed as aws lambdas using aws x-ray.

The set up is as follows:

1. Microservice A with api endpoint deployed as aws lambda
2. Microservice B with api endpoint deployed as aws lambda calling microservice A via https

Both microservices include the aws dependencies for xray:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-apache-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-instrumentor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For both microservices, tracing has been enabled via the serverless application model sam.yaml file:

```
Resources:
  FunctionA:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: example.HandlerA::handleRequest
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri: target/foo.jar
      MemorySize: 512
      Tracing: Active
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess 
      Timeout: 20
      Events:
        GetResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: any
```

While I can see the traces for the individual calls for the services A and B in the x-ray web interface, a call of B over A does not appear as a compound trace.

Any ideas? Probably I need to instantiate a servlet filter. Just including the dependencies will not be enough, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time, Amazon API Gateway is [not propagating `x-amzn-trace-id` headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-services-apigateway.html).

It sounds as if your AWS Lambda functions may be deployed behind API Gateway endpoints. Because of this limitation in API Gateway's integration with AWS X-Ray, tracing this operation as one continuous trace will not be possible today.

One approach for tracing this operation in a single continuous trace is having microservice B invoke microservice A directly using the AWS Lambda `Invoke` API. This API does respect the `x-amzn-trace-id` header (which would be automatically added to the `Invoke` request, as you've included the `aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-instrumentor` artifact in your project).

Comment: Wow. That's a bummer. Thanks for the link. Yes, seems like service B needs to invoke A via a lambda call in order to get a compound trace.